# How to convert this nested json string to a java object?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON string in a "special" format.
I want to convert it to an object in java but I don't know how to access single values for example the value of location or "resolved_at".

I tried with GSON and JSONPOBJECT but it doesn't work with this one.

```
 {
  "result": {
    "upon_approval": "proceed",
    "location": {
      "link": "https://instance.service-  now.com/api/now/table/cmn_location/108752c8c611227501d4ab0e392ba97f",
      "value": "108752c8c611227501d4ab0e392ba97f"
    },
    "expected_start": "",
    "reopen_count": "",
    "sys_domain": {
      "link": "https://instance.service-  now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
      "value": "global"
    },
    "description": "",
    "activity_due": "2016-01-22 16:12:37",
    "sys_created_by": "glide.maint",
    "resolved_at": "",
    "assigned_to": {
      "link": "https://instance.service-  now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/681b365ec0a80164000fb0b05854a0cd",
      "value": "681b365ec0a80164000fb0b05854a0cd"
    },
    "business_stc": "",
    "wf_activity": "",
    "sys_domain_path": "/",
    "cmdb_ci": {
      "link": "https://instance.service-  now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci/281190e3c0a8000b003f593aa3f20ca6",
      "value": "281190e3c0a8000b003f593aa3f20ca6"
    },
    "opened_by": {
      "link": "https://instance.service-  now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/glide.maint",
      "value": "glide.maint"
    },
    "subcategory": "",
    "comments": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes this JSON "special"?

Comment: you can generate pojo using jsonschema2pojo.com

Comment: @Henry I am used to this format: {"first":"a", "second":b"} here we have {"result": {"first":"a", "second":"b"}}

Comment: @AyoubRossi right but what is the difference? In both cases you'd be doing the same thing - reading values related to each key, assessing their type, covering that type. If you are using a JSON deserialisation library, then most of that would be handled for you already, you just need to supply some of the details about types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an object and use the objectmapper like:

```
Myclass myclass = objectMapper.readValue(json, Myclass.class);
```

But according to https://jsoneditoronline.org/ your json is not valid.

Used an online converter to create the classes, after removing the errors:

```
    -----------------------------------com.example.AssignedTo.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AssignedTo {

@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.CmdbCi.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CmdbCi {

@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Result result;

public Result getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(Result result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Location.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Location {

@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.OpenedBy.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class OpenedBy {

@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Result.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("upon_approval")
@Expose
private String uponApproval;
@SerializedName("location")
@Expose
private Location location;
@SerializedName("expected_start")
@Expose
private String expectedStart;
@SerializedName("reopen_count")
@Expose
private String reopenCount;
@SerializedName("sys_domain")
@Expose
private SysDomain sysDomain;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("activity_due")
@Expose
private String activityDue;
@SerializedName("sys_created_by")
@Expose
private String sysCreatedBy;
@SerializedName("resolved_at")
@Expose
private String resolvedAt;
@SerializedName("assigned_to")
@Expose
private AssignedTo assignedTo;
@SerializedName("business_stc")
@Expose
private String businessStc;
@SerializedName("wf_activity")
@Expose
private String wfActivity;
@SerializedName("sys_domain_path")
@Expose
private String sysDomainPath;
@SerializedName("cmdb_ci")
@Expose
private CmdbCi cmdbCi;
@SerializedName("opened_by")
@Expose
private OpenedBy openedBy;
@SerializedName("subcategory")
@Expose
private String subcategory;
@SerializedName("comments")
@Expose
private String comments;

public String getUponApproval() {
return uponApproval;
}

public void setUponApproval(String uponApproval) {
this.uponApproval = uponApproval;
}

public Location getLocation() {
return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
this.location = location;
}

public String getExpectedStart() {
return expectedStart;
}

public void setExpectedStart(String expectedStart) {
this.expectedStart = expectedStart;
}

public String getReopenCount() {
return reopenCount;
}

public void setReopenCount(String reopenCount) {
this.reopenCount = reopenCount;
}

public SysDomain getSysDomain() {
return sysDomain;
}

public void setSysDomain(SysDomain sysDomain) {
this.sysDomain = sysDomain;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getActivityDue() {
return activityDue;
}

public void setActivityDue(String activityDue) {
this.activityDue = activityDue;
}

public String getSysCreatedBy() {
return sysCreatedBy;
}

public void setSysCreatedBy(String sysCreatedBy) {
this.sysCreatedBy = sysCreatedBy;
}

public String getResolvedAt() {
return resolvedAt;
}

public void setResolvedAt(String resolvedAt) {
this.resolvedAt = resolvedAt;
}

public AssignedTo getAssignedTo() {
return assignedTo;
}

public void setAssignedTo(AssignedTo assignedTo) {
this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
}

public String getBusinessStc() {
return businessStc;
}

public void setBusinessStc(String businessStc) {
this.businessStc = businessStc;
}

public String getWfActivity() {
return wfActivity;
}

public void setWfActivity(String wfActivity) {
this.wfActivity = wfActivity;
}

public String getSysDomainPath() {
return sysDomainPath;
}

public void setSysDomainPath(String sysDomainPath) {
this.sysDomainPath = sysDomainPath;
}

public CmdbCi getCmdbCi() {
return cmdbCi;
}

public void setCmdbCi(CmdbCi cmdbCi) {
this.cmdbCi = cmdbCi;
}

public OpenedBy getOpenedBy() {
return openedBy;
}

public void setOpenedBy(OpenedBy openedBy) {
this.openedBy = openedBy;
}

public String getSubcategory() {
return subcategory;
}

public void setSubcategory(String subcategory) {
this.subcategory = subcategory;
}

public String getComments() {
return comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
this.comments = comments;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.SysDomain.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SysDomain {

@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
```

Edit: As i see, the code above will not work OOTB. I've got it working doeing the following steps:

- Replace @SerializedName with @JsonProperty

then:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Example example = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);
```

Comment: I tried but I get null values instead of the right values